# Best way of writing and reading multiple list of lists or arrays of arrays with different dimensions to and from file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some parameters and functions that I need to write to a file, but the functions and x-values have different lengths, i.e. domains and codomains, when compared to each other.
My current formatting, assuming e.g. two parameters A and B and two functions f1 and f2 is `[A,B,x,f1,f2]` where then `x, f1, f2` are itself again lists or numpy arrays.

So my imagined `data.txt` could look like this:

```
[0,  0, [0,1,2,3],       [1,2,3,4],       [4,5,6,7]]
[0,  1, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
[1, 10, [2,3,4,5,6],     [1,2,3,4,5],     [4,5,6,7,8]]
```

Then I could read in line by line, getting the parameters A and B and plot the functions f1 and f2, given the right x-values.

To write to a file I use the following code, which almost gives me what I described above.

```
OutSummary=[A,B,x,f1,f2]
Out=str(OutSummary).replace('\n', '')  
f=open(filename,'a')
np.savetxt(f, [Out],fmt='%s')
f.close()
```

Currently, this produces entries like `[0, 1, array([  8.        ,   8.29229229,   8.58458458, ....`

The issue is now that reading in does not work, due to the different lengths of the x-values and function arrays, i.e.

```
PrevEntris = np.genfromtxt(filename,dtype=str)
```

(with dtype=str, or dtype=None, or no dtype given) gives me e.g.

`ValueError: Some errors were detected ! Line #7 (got 555 columns instead of 1105)`,
i.e. the x-values contained in the 7th line only had 555 entries, while the previous 6 had 1105.

I see that this is not good code, and I am saving arrays as strings, but I did not manage to find a better way. I'd be really interested to know if there is some advanced numpy way of handling this, or maybe even using a SQL database kind of thing rather than one .txt file? I spent the last few hours trying to make it work using json, but was not successful, yet (1st time user).
Thanks

Comment: If you want to write OutSummary to a file that you can import later with the same program, look at python's pickle command. Otherwise, if it's parameters, use the json commands. pickle guarantees that nothing changes, json is depending on your data, but easier to read in a text editor (but you already tried that). Using the str function to convert your data to string is not reversable, so that's not a good approach. [Also, since you're a beginner, google for PEP8 to learn that OutSummany should be written as out_summary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer form Icestrike411 works very well for me, especially for my requested formatting style. Additionally, I solved it another way in the meantime also using json, when slightly altering the format.

One data block could look like

```
new_data = {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 0.05,
        "X": [0,1,2,3,4]
}
```

and then I append it to the outfile  with the following function, running `append('some.txt', new_data)`:

```
def append(filename, new_entry):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as filea:
            content = json.load(filea)
    except:
        content=[]
        #print("Likely empty file.")

    content.append(new_entry)
    out=json.dumps(content).replace("},", "},\n") #new line for each entry in file

    with open(filename, "w") as fileb:
        fileb.write(out)
```

and then reading it with

```
with open(filename, "r") as file:
    contentr = json.load(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin `json` module, since Python lists and JSON have the same syntax. Here is some example code if you want to store each of the lists in a bigger list:

```
import json
f=open("data.txt")
lines=f.read().splitlines()


data=[json.loads(line) for line in lines]

f.close() #remember to close your files
```

Edit: I realized I should have used list comprehensions instead so I changed my response. Still works the same way, but is neater